# Mac can ping wifi hosts but not wired hosts

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-yosemite, wired

I have two macs running 10.10.5.

Both are connected on wifi.

They can both ping other wifi hosts.

They cannot ping hosts on the wired lan.

My android phone is also connected wifi and can ping all hosts, both wifi and wired.

If I connect my mac to the wired lan it can ping all hosts.

Where to start!

Comment: What does the LAN look like? Do you have one "router" or several?

Comment: I have one router, one vpn router that connect to the main router. When I connect wirelessly to that router I can ping hosts on the main router, its strange.